# JPA JPQL condition AND on LEFT JOIN

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have Project which can have 0 to many relationship with Path.  We do soft deletes for Path so I'm trying to generate a query that returns a Project with active Path's and if Project has no instances of Path I still want Project to be returned with no Path records.  Also, if Project has only deleted Path records I still want Project to be returned with no Path records.

In SQL it looks like this:

```
select *
from project p
LEFT JOIN path pa ON p.project_id = pa.project_id AND pa.deleted_flag = false
where  p.project_id = 1;
```

However I have tried JPA and HQL's WITH with limited success.
With criteriabuilder and JPQL but doesn't return Project with only deleted Paths

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
String q = "SELECT p FROM Project AS p " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.paths as pa " +
        "WHERE (pa.pathId is null OR pa.deletedFlag <> true) AND p.projectId = :projectId";
TypedQuery<Project> projectTypedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(q, Project.class);
```

Also tried via JPQL but it doesn't work as it returns deleted paths

```
String q = "SELECT p FROM Project AS p " +
    "LEFT JOIN Path pa ON pa.projectByProjectId.projectId = p.projectId AND pa.deletedFlag <> true " +
    "WHERE p.projectId = :projectId";
projectTypedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(q, Project.class);
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(q);
project = (Project) query.setParameter("projectId", projectId).getSingleResult();
```

HQL below also returns deleted paths:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
q = "SELECT p FROM Project AS p " +
    "LEFT JOIN p.paths pa with pa.deletedFlag = false " +
    "WHERE p.projectId = :projectId";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(q);
project = (Project) query.setParameter("projectId", projectId).getSingleResult();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: JPQL allows an "ON" clause to be defined on joins. You should NOT add the normal relation join part across the FK to the "ON" clause (since JPQL adds that itself). Instead you define the ON clause with the additional part (deletedFlag in your case)

Comment: Thanks Neil, however, I tried using ON and the query does not return a Project with Path's that have been soft deleted.  Works well if a Project has at least one active Path (deletedFlag set to false).

Comment: yes but what SQL is GENERATED By the JPA provider?

Comment: Hibernate creates several queries.  The first query does as expected and the query looks like it should with the AND statement after the LEFT JOIN ON.  However, there are queries after that unfortunately cause the issue.  My guess these queries come from my Entity having additional OneToOne  and OneToMany relationships.